# Display single category name in woocommerce loop

Tags: categories, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display woocommerce single item category in shop loop. And i am using hooks action. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);

function loop_title() { ?>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="feed-item-baslik"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php 
        global $post;
        $postcat = get_the_category( $term_id );

        if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
            echo esc_html( $postcat[0]->name );   
        }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'loop_title', 10);
?>
```

But it not displays category name. And i also tried get_queried_object and get_term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);
function loop_title() { 
global $post;?>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="feed-item-baslik"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            echo $terms[0]->name;
        }?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'loop_title', 10); ?>
```

Replaced **get_the_category()** with **get_the_terms()**. Hope this helps !!